# ARC __bridge cast Block_copy & Block_release

Tags: objective-c, ios, automatic-ref-counting

For some reason I want a block to execute during the next iteration of the run loop, so I came up with:

```
typedef void (^resizer_t)() ;

- (void) applyResizer: (resizer_t) resizer {
    resizer() ;
    Block_release(resizer) ;
}

- (void) usage {
    ...
    resizer_t resizer = ^() {
        // stuff
    } ;

    [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(applyResizer:)
                           withObject:(__bridge id) Block_copy((__bridge void *) resizer)
                        waitUntilDone:NO] ;
}
```

1. Isn't it ironic that I have to cast to void * the argument to
   *Block*_copy ?
2. Why is the compiler happy with my Block_release when it chokes
   on Block_copy without the bridge void * cast?

The code seems to work, I didn't detect a leak nor a premature release, but I'm a bit puzzled by the syntax ...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Block are treated as objects so ARC prevent you from casting them to `void *` without explicit bridged cast. It strange that your compiler doesn't complain on `Block_release`: it should (on my machine, it does).

Because ARC treats block as objects, you shouldn't need to use `Block_copy` nor `Block_release` anymore. Copy the block (with `-[NSObject copy]`) when you want it to move to the heap and let the compiler manage the remainder.

`-[NSObject performSelectorOnMainThread:withObject:waitUntilDone:]` retains the receiver and the parameter object until the method is invoked. So your block will be retained and released when required. All you have to do is ensure that the block isn't stored on the stack by sending the `copy` message before passing it to the method.

Moreover, there is a simpler way to dispatch the execution of a block: it's libdispatch (aka GCD).

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), resizer);
```

Comment: It's clear answer. I also recommend @verec to use a dispatch_async with the main queue.

Answer (score 4):

> I want a block to execute during the next iteration of the run loop

Well, that's why you've got `dispatch_after`. If you supply a tiny time value, it will have exactly the effect you're after: you give a block, and the block will execute as soon the current runloop finishes and the redraw moment has happened.

Or if you can live without insisting on a block, use `performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:` with a tiny delay value (even zero). That has the same effect.

What you're asking for is called "delayed performance" and is very common. So do it the common way, the way the framework gives you; don't try to get all weird and fancy like your code is doing.