# How to make GCAlertView support ARC?

Tags: ios, automatic-ref-counting, uialertview

I'm using this [GCAlertView](https://github.com/guicocoa/common-code-ios/blob/master/GCAlertView.m) in my ARC-enabled project. I tried to make it ARC compatible so I don't have to use -fno-objc-arc on that file. The errors come from `Block_copy()` and `Block_release()` macros. It says 'Cast of block pointer type 'void (^)(void)' to C pointer type 'const void *' requires a bridged cast'.

It seems like I have to use __bridge in the block variable somewhere. But I have no idea where to put it. (Also I don't know what it does!) `Block_copy()` and `Block_release()` are inside iOS framework so I cannot alter it. Any ideas?

Comment: Take a look at this question, it may help you out.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9701923/arc-bridge-cast-block-copy-block-release

Comment: Thanks! that explains a lot :) The question is similar to this question but not exactly the same. But the answer should be pretty much close. You can post that link or restate the answer as this question's answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the issue due to the way blocks are used in ARC.

Check out this question which would help you.

[ARC __bridge cast Block_copy & Block_release](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9701923/arc-bridge-cast-block-copy-block-release)